# PDO returns all NULL values for columns?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a strange issue here and am hoping someone has a solution. As stated in the question, MySQL returns data but all the values are `NULL`.

Here is the query:

```
public function getPort($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT c.id, c.port as number, d.type, d.spec, d.transfer as speed
            FROM details a
            LEFT JOIN port_to_drive b ON a.drive_id = b.drive_id
            LEFT JOIN port c ON b.port_id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN port_type d ON c.port_type = d.id
            WHERE a.id = $id";

    $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $stmt->fetchObject();
}
```

I am trying to return an object, but have also tried returning an array and the result is the same.

Here's what it returns:

```
object(stdClass)[116]
public 'id' => null
public 'number' => null
public 'type' => null
public 'spec' => null
public 'speed' => null
```

If I use `fetch()` and return an array, the indexes are there but values are still `NULL`. When I run this query directly in MySQL I get the data I am expecting.

Here are the attributes I'm setting on my PDO connection if it helps.

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
```

I suspect it may have to do with not selecting anything from the table in the `FROM` or `WHERE` clause.

Here is the result directly from MySQL. The query should definitely return a row.

[image]

Comment: As a guess, your query returns no rows. Have you tried executing the query directly? Also, why aren't you binding `$id`

Comment: I don't understand how, `$id` has a value and when I use that value with the query directly in MySQL it works.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said it returns rows in MySQL. What data type is `details.id`? What is the value of `$id`?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you get rows in MySQL? You haven't made a typo or anything in the PHP? I only ask as `ON c.port_type = d.id` seems odd given the rest of your joins / column names. I would have expected `c.port_type_id = d.id`

Comment: If I had to guess, you definitely have at least one record where `detail.id` matches `$id` but none of your joins are matching up. Because you're using `LEFT JOIN`, all the values will be `null`. There's either no match for `a.drive_id = b.drive_id` (should it be `b.id`?) or there's no match for `b.port_id = c.id`

Comment: I copy and paste the exact same query into mysql, replacing only the variable name with a value. I thought it may be because the variable is a string in php, but even after casting it into an integer it's the same result.
In the database `id` is `int AI PK`.

Comment: I finally discovered the problem. This function was wrapped in a try/catch block with a transaction. `a.drive_id` was also being populated in that same transaction. Since it had not commited yet, `a.drive_id` was essentially `null`. You were correct Phil.